# Eclipse Android programming new folders don't add in the code

Tags: java, android, eclipse-adt

im trying to add music to my app here is the code

```
super.onCreate(Heshamlovethecold);
    setContentView(R.layout.splash);
    ourSong = MediaPlayer.create(Splash.this, R.raw.skult);
    ourSong.start();
```

skult is the mp3 sound and the raw is the folder and the error is at the raw folder the fix till me to add raw class and when i do it go to the R.java and then the skult file give error

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dHb0m.png)

Comment: Can you please include the error message?

Comment: i have added a photo thank you for replaying me

Comment: Rename folder `mp3`  to `raw` and move it to `res` folder, your path now will be liked `res/raw/abc.mp3`, then build again.

Comment: thank you for replaying me but still have the same error